# H2O randomForest produces surprisingly large POJOs

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I am using tree-based models and have noticed a big difference between `GBM` and `randomForest` in terms of how the size of training dataset impacts the size of the produced POJO.

I would not expect the size of the training dataset to affect the size of the model object very much at all,* and this holds almost true for `GBM`.

However, for `randomForest`, there seems to be a linear relationship between number of training-set rows and size of the exported POJO.  This result:

```
Size of GBM with m =  1000 and p = 10: 0.15 MB (3281 lines)
Size of GBM with m =  1000 and p = 20: 0.16 MB (3501 lines)
Size of GBM with m = 10000 and p = 10: 0.18 MB (3833 lines)
Size of GBM with m = 10000 and p = 20: 0.19 MB (3899 lines)

Size of RF  with m =  1000 and p = 10:  4.38 MB ( 63908 lines)
Size of RF  with m =  1000 and p = 20:  4.40 MB ( 63606 lines)
Size of RF  with m = 10000 and p = 10: 45.84 MB (637168 lines) <- note 10x increase
Size of RF  with m = 10000 and p = 20: 46.08 MB (635059 lines)    on 10x training rows
```

is obtained from my benchmark script:

```
library(data.table)
library(h2o)

pojo_path <- getwd() # your folder here

options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)
h2o.init(max_mem_size = '8G')
h2o.no_progress()

m_range <- c(1e3,1e4)  # of rows
p_range <- c(10,20)    # of columns

for(p in p_range){
  for(m in m_range){
    # bunch of random data
    set.seed(1)
    mtrx <- matrix(runif(n=m*p), nrow=m, ncol=p)

    # some really random outcome
    set.seed(2)
    y = rowSums(t( t(mtrx)*runif(n=p) )) + rnorm(n=m,sd=0.1)

    dt   <- data.table( mtrx) 
    dt[, `:=`(y = y, id = .I)]
    setkey(dt,id)

    gbm_nm <- paste0('gbm_m_',m,'_p_',p)
    rf_nm <- paste0('rf_m_',m,'_p_',p)
    dt_h2o <- as.h2o(dt)


    gbm <- h2o.gbm(
             x = paste0('V',1:p),
             y = 'y',
             training_frame = dt_h2o,
             nfolds=10,
             model_id = gbm_nm
           )
    rf <- h2o.randomForest(
             x = paste0('V',1:p),
             y = 'y',
             training_frame = dt_h2o,
             nfolds=10,
             model_id = rf_nm
           )

    pojo_gbm_path <- file.path(pojo_path,h2o.download_pojo(gbm, path=pojo_path ) )
    writeLines(paste0('Size of GBM with m = ', m,
                      ' and p = ',p,': ',
                      round(file.info(pojo_gbm_path
                                      )$size/(2^20),2),
                      ' MB (',length(readLines(pojo_gbm_path)),
                      ' lines)'
                      )
    )
    pojo_rf_path <- file.path(pojo_path,h2o.download_pojo(rf, path=pojo_path))
    writeLines(paste0('Size of RF  with m = ', m,
                      ' and p = ',p,': ',
                      round(file.info(pojo_rf_path
                                      )$size/(2^20),2),
                      ' MB (',length(readLines(pojo_rf_path)),
                      ' lines)'
    )
    )
  }
}
```

The size of the `randomForest` objects is becoming prohibitively large on datasets I'm working with.

Why is this happening?  Is this behavior inherent to `randomForest` (so decide whether to downsample or use something else) or is there something I can do about it?

[*] I understand that more training data will allow more splits if parameters like min_leaf_size are binding.  But after a certain point, we would expect those to be sufficed and object size to stop growing.

[**] I'm on H2O v 3.20.0.8, R version 3.5.1

Comment: please don't just tell me to switch to MOJOs.  I have a workflow in place for now that expects a POJO.

Comment: If your dataset has N rows, and your random forest has a leaf size of X (fixed), how many leaves do you expect to get?

Comment: @HongOoi I guess, worst-case, something on the order of `n.trees*2^max_depth`, which doesn't depend on N, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a smaller depth.  The default depth in DRF is much bigger than for GBM, and most of the size growth is probably due to that.

You can also use a smaller number of trees.

Switching to MOJO would probably also reduce size by about 10x.

Comment: I can confirm that when RF is set to `max_depth=5` (this is default for GBM), the POJO sizes are very close and do not increase with N.  Under the default `max_depth` values, GBM has a max of 2^5 leaves per tree (plus proxy splits if there's missing data, I suppose) but RF has a max of 2^20 or 1 megaleaves.

Comment: Best to switch to MOJO unless you need a POJO.